# How to use foreman between 2 repo?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, foreman

I have a project. Although it is the same website, the front and back ends are divided into 2 repo(s), which are made by React and Ruby on Rails respectively. Therefore, every time I want to start a website locally, I must open 2 Ubuntu terminal windows.

I heard that foreman can start both at once. Are there any examples to learn from? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add `foreman` gem to you Gemfile and create `Procfile.dev` file in your root directory.

Inside of it, you add all of the processes you want to launch. So, it could be something like this:

```
backend: bin/rails server -p 3000
frontend: npm start
```

*Obviously, you can use whatever you use to start your frontend application.*

And then you run `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` in your terminal.

Comment: Editing Gemfile to install foreman is the behavior in Rails. My Rails repo and React repo are two directories with different names. I'm not sure if this can recognize React.
I don't understand the relevant principles very much, sorry.